# Switch case in aspectj logging

Tags: enums, aspectj

I'm using load time aspectj for logging my methods and im using "afterThrowing" annotation to log my exceptions. in the afterThrowing method i have a switch case to determine what type of log level to use (INFO, WARN,DEBUG....), the log level is implemented as an enum.

```
switch (Exp.getLoggingLevel()) {
        case INFO:
            logger.info(
                String.format(
                          ERROR_MESSAGE,
                          joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                          joinPoint.getSignature().getName()),
                Exp);
            break;
        case DEBUG:
            logger.debug(
                 String.format(
                           ERROR_MESSAGE,
                           joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                           joinPoint.getSignature().getName()),
                 netoExp);
            break;
        case TRACE:
            logger.trace(
                 String.format(
                           ERROR_MESSAGE,
                           joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                           joinPoint.getSignature().getName()),
                 Exp);
            break;
        case WARN:
            logger.warn(
                String.format(
                          ERROR_MESSAGE,
                          joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                          joinPoint.getSignature().getName()),
                Exp);
            break;
```

we are concern this is not the most efficient way. is there a different way?

Answer (score 0):

why not? unfortunalty when you call

```
   logger.warn (String.format(...
```

fisrtly java execute String.format (quite expensive) second execute the method warn; if the log level is ERROR the "String.format" call is totally unnecessary.

I think the problem is elsewhere:

- due to the logging algorithm
- due to the reflection

which logging framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using slf4j. how can i do a log level check before the switch? is't it a messy code?

Comment: lior, slf4j is a Facade for logback or log4j; you can use the native methods "info/debug/warn/error(String format, Object... arguments)" and you can link the code to different aspects  implementing the 4 log level

Comment: venergiac, is there a way to pointcut an aspect by logging level? can you please elaborate on the second suggestion you made?

Comment: Yes you can define a method for each different logging level and second you can pointcut (it depends from you framework, Annotation or pattern on spring) customizing "execution(* *(String, ..))"; however, why you are using level INFO or DEBUG on AfterThrowing annotation? You have tu use ERROR?!?

Comment: Thank you! and i'm not using ERROR because we have exceptions we dont define as errors

Comment: Ah ok then you can use @AfterThrowing(
    pointcut="METHOD",
    throwing="ex")
  public void log(MyException ex) {

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand your answer. what is this log aspect for?

Comment: Supposing the an apscet like that http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/09/using-aspectjs-afterthrowing-advice-in.html#.UsqpN3VDvDg, you can use (never tried) on the same aspect different overloaded log method @AfterThrowing( pointcut="METHOD", throwing="ex")log(JoinPoint joinPoint, MyException1 ex) and @AfterThrowing( pointcut="METHOD", throwing="ex")log(JoinPoint joinPoint, MyException2 ex)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using java8, consider making a functional interface `LoggingMethod` with one method `void log(String msg, Exp exp)`. you then can assign the `LoggingMethod` in the case like `method = logger::warn`. then only one call to `method.log(string.format(...), exp)`.

better yet, have the `LoggingLevel` return the LoggingMethod. you dont need java8 for that, you can use inter-type declarations to add it.